# Retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, null

I need to return a read data from Firebase. Here is the code:

```
private String getInfo(DatabaseReference reference) {
   String string = "";
   reference.child("xxx").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       string = snapshot.getValue().toString();
       // here the log display the correct value I need
       Log.i("Log", string);  
   }

   onCancelled() ...
   }
});
return string; // HERE THE VALUE IS NULL!!!!
```

As written above the log show the correct value, but when I try to return it its value becomes null.

Comment: That's the classic issue with asynchronous programming. Note that Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a custom callback or other two options mentioned in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Answer (score 0):

It's within the inner block, that's why it happens
Move the return function to the inside of the block so it will show the correct value

Comment: If I move the return statement in the inner block it says me that the method is void and can't return the value

Answer (score 0):

First try moving the `return string;` inside the method body, then if it doesn't help read below.

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` executes onDataChange method immediately and after executing that method once, it stops listening to the reference location it is attached to.

So instead use `addValueEventListener()`, which keeps listening to the query or database reference it is attached to as mentioned here [Read and Write Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

Here is another useful information from the official documentation:

> The listener receives a DataSnapshot that contains the data at the
> specified location in the database at the time of the event. Calling
> getValue() on a snapshot returns the Java object representation of the
> data. If no data exists at the location, calling getValue() returns
> null.
>
> In this example, ValueEventListener also defines the onCancelled()
> method that is called if the read is canceled. For example, a read can
> be canceled if the client doesn't have permission to read from a
> Firebase database location. This method is passed a DatabaseError
> object indicating why the failure occurred.